# How can I align an image to the top of a cell in civimail?

Tags: civimail, images

Currently it is displaying in the middle...

```
        </td>
        <td style="width: 232px;">
        <div style="text-align:center">
        <figure class="image" style="display:inline-block"><img alt="" height="353" src="...jpg" width="250" />
        <figcaption>Name AM</figcaption>
        </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<`figure`>` tag, you could try changing it to `<`figure class="image" style="display:inline-block vertical-align: top;"`>`  Does that work?

Incidentally, there should be a semi-colon after "inline-block" and in the `<`div`>` tag after "center".

If this doesn't work, could you say what CSS you have in the class="image"

**Edit1** On reflection, I dont think the above will work.  You could try the following:

```
</td>
            <td style="width: 232px; text-align: center;"><img alt="" height="353" src="...jpg" style="vertical-align: top;" width="250" />
            <figure class="image" style="display:inline-block">
            <figcaption>Name AM</figcaption>
            </figure>
            </td>
```

Do you need all the CSS in the `<figure>` tag?